# Create a table of contents (toc) in a post with blogdown package

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I know the short answer, add the following in the metadata `toc: TRUE`

But when I create a post with the blogdown package that have a table of content, I have problems with the url (redirection) behind the table options.

The links for the table of content are of the following form:

http://home-website/#tree-terminology

Instead to be:

http://home-website/post_name/#tree-terminology

**How can reference the name of the post correctly in the url to generate the proper url in the table of content? In which part can find the configuration behind the toc behavior?**

Answer (score 3):

As per Yihui's Github (https://github.com/yihui/hugo-xmin/pull/7), you might need to put

```
output:
  blogdown::html_page:
    toc: true
```

in your YAML. It's working properly on my website.

Comment: I still have problems with the incorrect redirection of the table of content, I think that the problem has to be with relative urls in the config toml.

Comment: Yeah, maybe check the documentation at https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/configuration.html#options