# Cannot get a toc with Rmd using blogdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown

I'm attempting to add a table of contents to a blogdown page using yaml. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119371/create-a-table-of-contents-toc-in-a-post-with-blogdown-package) before posting. Also read through docs.

Within rstudio if I create a new project and choose the new blogdown site option, a dir is auto populated and I can then `blogdown::build_site(build_rmd = T)` followed by `blogdown::serve_site()` to see a hellow world example site served locally. It defaults to the lithium-ion theme.

[image]

There is an auto created post 'Hello R Markdown' at `content/post/2020-12-01-r-rmarkdown/index.Rmd` that contains this yml:

```
---
title: "Hello R Markdown"
author: "Frida Gomam"
date: 2020-12-01T21:13:14-05:00
categories: ["R"]
tags: ["R Markdown", "plot", "regression"]
---
```

I added some sections:

```
## bla

bla

## ha 

ha
```

I wanted to add a table of contents toc. Tried several things, including:

```
---
title: "Hello R Markdown"
author: "Frida Gomam"
date: 2020-12-01T21:13:14-05:00
categories: ["R"]
tags: ["R Markdown", "plot", "regression"]
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true # table of content true
---
```

Also tried:

```
---
title: "Hello R Markdown"
author: "Frida Gomam"
date: 2020-12-01T21:13:14-05:00
categories: ["R"]
tags: ["R Markdown", "plot", "regression"]
output:
  blogdown::html_page:
    toc: true
---
```

In each case, when I build and serve, no toc is rendered.

How can I add a table of contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to generate the TOC:

1. Set `options(blogdown.method = 'html')` in your `.Rprofile` (the default method is `'markdown'`). Then restart R, delete `index.md`, and serve the site again. This method requires the YAML setting:

   ```yaml
   output:
     blogdown::html_page:
       toc: true
   ```

   This method uses Pandoc to generate the TOC.
2. If you don't change the `blogdown.method` option, you need to modify the Hugo template `single.html` [like this](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium/commit/ee43e4a47aa3176bcbb818ca7ab0d1cc54466d1d), and then set the top-level YAML option `toc: true`. Note that Hugo generates the TOC starting from level-2 headings [by default](https://gohugo.io/content-management/toc/), so your body should start with `##` headings. If you have to start with level-1 headings, you need to [configure Hugo](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration-markup/#table-of-contents) in `config.yaml` (or `hugo.yaml` for recent versions of Hugo).

Personally I'd recommend the second method.